# abspath definition Django

Tags: django, django-settings

What's the difference between these two in `settings.py` of Django project

`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `abspath` will create a clean directory name, from root. For example `../dir` may be converted to `/path/to/dir` (Or `C:\...` for Windows).

However the double `dirname` call does not seem useful.